# Node.d.ts issues errors using typescript compiler, how do I fix?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, typescript, jasmine, protractor

I have a project that's a NODE console application project using Visual Studio 2013.  When I compile the solution I'm getting typescript errors as follows:

Typescript wants a semicolon after

```
export interface ReadableStream extends EventEmitter {
    readable: boolean;
    read(size?: number): string|Buffer;
    //Like this ----> read(size?: number): string;|Buffer;
```

Which means I have to get rid of the pipe Buffer; if I do that it I have a lot of other problems for modules that implement this interface...

I downloaded the definitely-typed definitions about a month ago, perhaps they're outdated?

One thing is for sure using TS in NODE console applications is a bit of a challenge... any tips are appreciated in advance.

Comment: You might need to update your TS version in VS. `string|Buffer` is a union type which was introduced in version 1.4 (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/01/16/announcing-typescript-1-4.aspx) there are other questions/answers that explain how to update TS in VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Typescript wants a semicolon after

You are using an older version of TypeScript. Upgrade to TypeScript 1.4 or later.